# I can see java 11 when I am checking version through command prompt but why it's showing java 17 when I am checking version in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, java-17

its showing below details while checking 'java -version' in CMD

java version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.15+8-LTS-149)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.15+8-LTS-149, mixed mode)

I am getting below response in Eclipse while using 'System.getProperty("java.version")'

Java Version is: 17.0.2

Comment: I guess the Java 17.0.2 is the Java that is shipped with Eclipse 2022-03 and the Java 11.0.15 is a Java that you have installed on your system. See preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ which Java JREs/JDKs you have configured in order to be used in your projects and launch configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The CMD uses the `PATH` environment variable to search for executables (`java.exe`). The executable is searched in the directories listed in that variable, in the given order. The first one found, is the one that is executed.

---

Eclipse uses its own settings:

1. the JRE used to start Eclipse *can* be specified in the `eclipse.ini` file; if not specified there, the OS default will be used (usually the same as the CMD, see above);
2. the JRE used to execute an application inside Eclipse, is specified by the Run/Debug configurations (<kbd>Run</kbd>-<kbd>Run Configurations...</kbd>/<kbd>Run</kbd>-<kbd>Debug Configurations...</kbd>), the respective project properties (<kbd>Project</kbd>-<kbd>Properties</kbd>) and Eclipse preferences (<kbd>Window</kbd>-<kbd>Preferences</kbd>-<kbd>Java</kbd>-<kbd>Installed JREs</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

When I chose "Use Default Workspace JRE" inside Java Build Path->JRE System Library it is showing Java 11.0.15 in eclipse